# Removing date/time styling from HTML email iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email, html-email

I've created a responsive HTML email which works fine across many different platforms except when viewed on iPhone.

It seems that iOS is recognising a date + time and applying a blue colour/underline to the content. I've researched this issue for the past couple hours and am at a dead end.

I've tried turning format detection off for phone numbers:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

I've tried including `date` and `address` in this too:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no">
```

I've tried adding `!important` to the styles on the element with still no luck:

```
<h4 style="font-size: 16px;color: #FFFFFF !important; text-decoration:none !important;font-family: Arial;font-weight: bold;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 1.3;word-break: normal;" class="appleLinksWhite">
    Thursday 20th November
</h4>

<p style="color: #FFFFFF !important; text-decoration:none !important;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 0;font-family: Arial;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 19px;font-size: 14px !important;" class="appleLinksWhite">
    10:45am until 12:30pm,<br>The Feast, Suffolk Food Hall, Ipswich
</p>
```

I've tried adding a class to the elements `.appleLinksWhite` as recommended [here](https://litmus.com/blog/remove-blue-links-ios) which still did not do the trick.

I have also tried wrapping the inner contents in a `<span>` with the colour and text-decoration set and this still didn't work.

I'm at a loss for other things to try. How can I disable this behaviour?

Edit* It's worth noting that the issue is only with iPhone 4/5. iPhone 6/Plus are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working by tricking the date detection algorithm into thinking it's not dealing with a date by inserting a zero width `&#8203;` character in between my date/time strings e.g:

```
<h4 style="font-size: 16px;color: #FFFFFF !important; text-decoration:none !important;font-family: Arial;font-weight: bold;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 1.3;word-break: normal;" class="appleLinksWhite">
    Thursday&#8203; 20th&#8203; November&#8203;
</h4>

<p style="color: #FFFFFF !important; text-decoration:none !important;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 0;font-family: Arial;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 19px;font-size: 14px !important;" class="appleLinksWhite">
    10:45am&#8203; until&#8203; 12:30pm&#8203;,<br>The Feast, Suffolk Food Hall, Ipswich
</p>
```

Comment: This fix works but instead of &#8203; I had to use &zwnj; changing 11:00​‌AM​​-11:30‌​AM​​ ET
to
11&zwnj;:&zwnj;00&zwnj;‌AM&zwnj;-11&zwnj;:&zwnj;30‌&zwnj;AM&zwnj; ET

Answer (score 9):

This will eliminate the blue+underline styling (tested on iPhone 5, iOS 8.3):

```
a[href^="x-apple-data-detectors"] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: This works! I did have to make the styles !important and omit the : to make it work, a[href^="x-apple-data-detectors"]{
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: inherit !important;
}
*thank you*, @Christian.